# Show that functions of one equation satisfy another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

I am trying to show that if $A(x) $ and $ B(t)$ are a solution to

$$c A(x) + d B(t) = 0$$

where $c$ and $d$ are non-zero constants, then $A(x) $ and $ B(t)$ automatically satisfy

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x} A(x) = 0$$

I think the way to show this is just to take the partial derivative with respect to x of the first equations. So

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x}  \left[ c A(x) + d B(t)\right] = c \frac{\delta}{\delta x} A(x) = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\delta}{\delta x} A(x) = 0$$

Is this the correct way to show that claim? Is there anything that can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, with $\delta$ you mean $\partial$ that is `\partial`. Your proof is correct, but I rather advise you to do it as follows: for any $x$ you have that
$$
  A(x) = \frac dc B(t)
$$
and thus the derivatives of lhs and rhs w.r.t. $x$ coincide:
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}A(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac dc B(t) = 0.
$$